# Having issue connecting MySQL to Spring Boot Application in EKS Cluster in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes

I tried almost every resource I could to try to fix the issue of trying to connect a mysql database to my spring boot application and I had no such luck. Here is the complete code at the bottom. Any idea from the code that could be causing the issue?

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
name: mysql-credentials
data:
username: bXlzcWw=
password: bXlzcWw=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: mysql-conf
data:
host: mysql
dbName: engineersdb
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: mysql-pv-volume
labels:
type: local
spec:
storageClassName: manual
capacity:
storage: 2Gi
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
storageClassName: manual
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
resources:
requests:
storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: mysql
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app: mysql
strategy:
type: Recreate
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: mysql
spec:
containers:
- image: mysql:5.7
name: mysql
env:
- name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
valueFrom :
secretKeyRef :
name : mysql-credentials
key :  password

```
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE # Setting Database Name from a 'ConfigMap'
              valueFrom :
                configMapKeyRef :
                  name : mysql-conf
                  key :  dbName

        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30007ms.] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.engineers.core.engineersuserservice.EngineersProjectApplication.main(EngineersProjectApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30007ms.] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30007ms.] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.getIsolatedConnection(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropTables(SchemaDropperImpl.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30007ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${DB_HOST}3306: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:934) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1385) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar:8.0.24]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/${DB_NAME}?useSSL=false
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: engineers-user-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  engineers-user-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:  engineers-user-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  engineers-user-service
          image: steven8519/engineers-user-service
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env: # Setting Enviornmental Variables
            - name: DB_HOST   # Setting Database host address from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-conf
                  key: host

            - name: DB_NAME  # Setting Database name from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-conf
                  key: dbName

            - name: DB_USERNAME  # Setting Database username from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-credentials
                  key: username

            - name: DB_PASSWORD # Setting Database password from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-credentials
                  key: password
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%  # Maximum unavailable pods during update
      maxSurge: 25%  # Maximum additional pods to create during update
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  engineers-user-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: engineers-user-service
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30082
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080



<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below observation from my side

Check Database Availability: Ensure that the MySQL database is up and running and that it's accessible from your Kubernetes cluster. You can test the database connection using command-line tools or other clients.

Verify Connection Details: Double-check the spring.datasource.url, DB_HOST, and other connection properties in your application.properties or application.yml configuration. Make sure the host name, port, and other connection details are correct.

Use Environment Variables: In your Kubernetes environment, make sure that the environment variables (DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) are correctly defined in your ConfigMap and Secret.

Networking Configuration: Ensure that your Kubernetes cluster's networking configuration allows communication between your Spring Boot application and the MySQL database. Check security groups, network policies, and firewall rules.

DNS Resolution: Confirm that the DNS resolution in your Kubernetes cluster is working correctly. It should be able to resolve the host name (DB_HOST) to the correct IP address.

Database Driver: Verify that you have the correct MySQL database driver version (mysql-connector-java) in your application's dependencies.

HikariCP Configuration: Review the HikariCP configuration in your application.properties or application.yml to make sure it's properly configured.

Database Health: Consider implementing a health check endpoint in your Spring Boot application to check the data